# IE10 Swagger Error Failed to parse JSON/YAML

Tags: internet-explorer, swagger-2.0, window.location

This is more of a general question. My Swagger API works fine when I am using IE11, Chrome, FireFox, and more but IE10 and down I am getting an Error: `failed to parse JSON/YAML` and in my `swagger.inspec().state` is coming back `"rejected"`.

Here is how I am instantiating my client:

```
import { API_URI } from '../config/app_config'; // '/accountservice/swagger.json'
import Swagger from 'swagger-client'; //   "swagger-client": "^2.1.17"

export const buildAccountServiceClient = () => {
  const swagger = new Swagger({
    url: (!window.location.origin ? IE_API_URI : API_URI),
    usePromise: true,
  });

  // Reconfigure swagger client to override service path if we're using a reverse proxy:
  // /accountservice/swagger.json -> /accountservice
  // Originally tried setting basePath to null, undefined, and '', but that didn't work
  let basePath;
  if (API_URI.startsWith('/')) {
    basePath = API_URI.substring(0, API_URI.lastIndexOf('/'));
    swagger.then((client) => {
      client.setBasePath(basePath);
      if (typeof(window) !== 'undefined') {
        // use current protocol, so either http or https
        client.setSchemes([window.location.protocol.slice(0, -1)]);
      }
    });
  }
  return swagger;
};
```

I am also using a proxy server which is why I have the API_URI not defined as the full url but just the path.

Why would this work in all other browsers except IE10 even though IE10 is supported?

Comment: Which version of Swagger UI? The latest 3.0.x [does not support IE10](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui#browser-support).

Comment: nope I am using `"swagger-client": "^2.1.17"` 

I added a little more context here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js/issues/1018

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After diving through Swagger-JS source code in my node_modules folder.

What I discovered was the initializing method was trying to grab the current window locations "origin" to add to the front of the url path that was passed to the constructor.

Since there is no `origin` key in the IE10 window object, it was translating the url to be `undefined/swagger.json`.

To fix this I made the change below:

`node_modules/swagger-client/lib/client.js line:129`

```
  line 126  if(this.url && this.url.indexOf('http:') === -1 && this.url.indexOf('https:') === -1) {
  line 127   // no protocol, so we can only use window if it exists
  line 128   if(typeof(window) !== 'undefined' && window && window.location) {
  line 129     this.url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + this.url;
  line 130   }
  line 131 }
```

In IE10, the window object does not contain an object key called `location.origin` when other browsers do.

So if you want to get this to work in IE10:

```
line 129 this.url = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + this.url;
```

I am gunna try and submit a PR to swagger to get this fixed.

**--UPDATE--**

If you do not want to wait for the PR to go through and need a fix on your end:

http://tosbourn.com/a-fix-for-window-location-origin-in-internet-explorer/

Or here is my fix:

```
const API_URI = '/swagger.json';
const IE_API_URI = `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.hostname}${(window.location.port ? `:${window.location.port}` : '')}/swagger.json`;

const swagger = new Swagger({
  url: (!window.location.origin ? IE_API_URI : API_URI),
  usePromise: true,
});
```